# trying to start SymmetricDS as service in WIndows returning native error 19

Tags: windows, windows-services, symmetricds

I am trying to install SymmetricDS as a service. The SymmetricDS version I am using is `symmetric-server-3.7.27`. I am following the process mentioned in the SymmetricDS documentation [webpage](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_running_as_a_service). It uses `sym_service` to install and then start the service. The installation seems to be successful but when I am trying to start it from console, I am getting the following error: [image]

which in English translates to:

> Error 19: Start Service returned error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request. Native error 19

As far I found there is a `sym_service.conf` file in the conf folder that can be manipulated for changing the service properties. But I am not sure actually this error has anything to do with the conf file.

Comment: Is there a log file? Are there any exceptions there?

Comment: as far I know the log for symmetricds is in `symmds_path/logs` but there is no file. So I guess no logs are created from symmetricds

Comment: i am also getting same error, Did you get any workaround?

Comment: Same problem here, but with version 3.8.0...any advice? Thank you

Comment: @mginius The main issue was "wrapper.java.command" in the sym_service.conf file. Also sym_service.bat uses setenv.bat to set java for symmetricds, the absolute path to the java had to be explicitly configured in the sym_service.conf file. Since then it worked fine for me.

Comment: Ok, thank you @ShaDooW. I'll give it a try. Since now I created a task (within Task Scheduler section), to accomplish my job (run service at startup), but I know it'll be better to your its own service. Thanks for your answer.